# Command menu contribution adds parameter names to the label

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, contextmenu

I have the following `menuContribution`, adding one command to the context menu of a `Tree`. There are two technical parameters `expand` and `useSelection`.

```
<menuContribution
    locationURI="popup:com.softmodeler.ui.editors.StructureCompareEditor?after=additions">
 <command
       commandId="softmodeler.cmd.refreshViewer"
       id="softmodeler.cmd.refreshViewer"
       style="push">
    <parameter
          name="expand"
          value="1">
    </parameter>
    <parameter
          name="useSelection"
          value="true">
    </parameter>
 </command>
</menuContribution>
```

This shows up in the `Tree` as follows:
[image: context menu with parameter appended]

Any idea how to get rid of the parameter names in the label?

I could set the `label` attribute on the `command` but then I would have redundant labels (supporting four UI languages, trying to prevent redundancy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a label attribute, otherwise this default label will be used. For localization, use `%label` in the attribute value and provide `plugin.properties` files for each language (but I guess you know that already). From what I know that's as good as it gets.

Alternatively, you can create menu contributions programmatically, providing an `ExtensionContributionFactory`. Within the `createContributionItems()` method you should be able to create contribution items from the desired commands while re-using the command names as labels. This will, of course, activate your plug-ins as soon as the menu is shown.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, yes I know about localization. I just would prefer to only define the label on the command once, especially this command I want to use in different menus, which would mean to maintain x labels. I'll leave the question open, just in case somebody knows a hack/workaround.

Comment: Sure, I also came across this redundancy in the past. The best I was able to come up with is using the same `%label` for all menus that reference the same command.

Comment: Just came across the same solution, wanted to post an answer and saw your comment. Luckily both command and menu declaration are in the same plugin.xml. This does the job for now.